# how to scan a barcode image in a meteor application

Tags: meteor

I'd like to put together a mobile-friendly data acquisition app 
This app would be used in a data center, which means working in a disconnected mode
This app also needs to carry (on the client) a mongodb collection of ASCI| character codes, to be matched with the incoming barcodes
Once being back online, this app should sync all acquired data with its back-end mongodb

Based on these requirements, I think, meteor would be a good choice

My questions is: are there meteor packages, that can scan an image, and then translate that image to an ASCII  character code?

Comment: Are you looking for a web camera ocr solution or something that can interface with an end-user ocr scanner via browser? (either way it's not about meteor)

Comment: Web camera. The app will run on users iPhone, as he walks in a data center and scans barcodes attached to servers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get barcode scanning capability, use [BarcodeScanner](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner) cordova plugin:

```
meteor add cordova:com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner@2.0.1
```

Template

```
<head>
  <title>Barcode Scanner</title>
</head>

<body
  {{> barcode_scanner}}
</body>

<template name="barcode_scanner">
  <button>Scan</button>
</template>
```

JS

```
if (Meteor.isCordova) {

  Template.barcode_scanner.events({
    'click button': function () {

      cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function (result) {
          alert("We got a barcode\n" +
            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
        }, 
        function (error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
        }
     );

    }

  });

}
```

For offline data capability, take a look [GroundDB](https://github.com/GroundMeteor/db)

Comment: When I run `meteor add` command, I get this output: `Added Cordova plugin phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner@2.0.1 (plugin has been
renamed as part of moving to npm).`  Do you have an updated command?

Comment: Remove existing plugin `meteor remove cordova:com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner` and try add latest plugin `meteor add cordova:phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner@4.0.2`

Comment: I can't get the scanner to run. I created a fresh new app, used above template and script. Added the plugin, and nothing happens when I click on the button. The barcode scanner simply refuses to start. Any pointers?

Comment: Sorry to bother. I figured it out. I'm using Ionic, so I have to wrap the call in `$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {});`

Comment: If you're using Meteor+Ionic+Angular, take a look http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/barcodeScanner